# Why would a door be installed without all the hinge screws?

Tags: doors

Our contractor installed this door without using all the screws (or perhaps the door came without enough screws). Every hinge on each side of these double doors is missing one screw on the frame side. Is there some hidden wisdom here?

[image]

Comment: Ask the contractor.

Comment: No wisdom, lack thereof is more likely. It's possible the contractor does not know how to install door properly or did not have the right hardware (long screws) on-hand.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just some notes:

1. This is just plain lazy.  Maybe he forgot but forgetting = lazy.
2. Maybe he ran out of screws.  But these are basically the most common type of door screws so again that goes back to being lazy.
3. When installing doors it is best practice to get at least one screw per hinge all the way into the actual framing of the wall.  This requires some pretty long screws - 2-2.5" at least.  He may not have had those screws on him.  Again that is not planning well and shouldn't have been left like this, which is lazy.

Comment: Yep, prehung exterior doors sometimes come with the screw missing that's intended to be driven into the frame of the house (since its size/composition will vary depending on your  home) and the contractor simply forgot/neglected to obtain and install the right ones.   Probably a "not my job" move like thinking it's beneath him to properly insulate around it.  Be on the lookout for other shortcuts.

Comment: #3 is a bingo. Manufacturers leave them out intentionally to encourage more robust installation. I'd get some 3" gold screws and pilot halfway or so, angling slightly toward the framing. That screw is very close to the edge of the stud and can easily glance off it.

Comment: @isherwood - I figure it is #3 but really all prehung doors I buy... and I do way too many damn doors... all come with all the screws for the hinges.  I get why a manufacturer might leave one out but I have never seen it.

Comment: Ok. I've installed many (usually exterior or solid-core) with packets of 2-1/2" gold screws stapled to the jambs.

Comment: @isherwood - dammit I don't get those by me.  I get the door with the short screws in each hinge... that is it.  Even for the expensive solid core doors.  Got to buy the long ones on their own.  Which has become a PITA lately with some people using satin nickel or even bronze hinges.  We can always find the regular ones at big box but usually have to order anything that isn't chrome or gold.

Comment: Ok, so I should fix this myself I guess. What kind of screws should I buy?

Comment: You just screw them into the frame through center of the hole - not rocket science.  As you screw it will be tough, then it will be shims or dead space, and then you should feel the screws catch on the framing.  https://www.hingeoutlet.com/collections/wood-screws/products/wdscrw-brass

Comment: `all the way into the actual framing of the wall` - Wall, or the door?

Comment: @Thebluefish wall.  You want the hinge secured to the framing of the wall, since the area around the frame is usually just hollow.  You want at least one screw to catch real load bearing wood so it doesn't fall down.

Comment: @DMoore Do you not need to pre-drill the holes?

Comment: Until it hits the wall and also no predrilling.  For the longer screws this would be useless.  I mean I guess if you want to be 110% sure you hit the middle you could use a tiny bit down the middle to act as a pilot for the screw.

Comment: Since there's probably no shim behind the empty screw hole, don't over tighten the long screws or you could deform the door jamb.  All screws should go through shims to prevent the jamb from being pulled out of wack.  If the installer didn't know or care enough to use the right screws, they probably didn't shim solidly enough either.

Answer (score 9):

The door comes already attached to the frame, with all those screws you see. These are rather short screws as they can't be longer than the thickness of the frame, since it's an assembled unit.

The missing screw on the frame side is to be a *long* screw. That goes through the frame, through any surface material in the hole in the wall, and into the structural member of the wall.

Use the longest deck screw you can find, if you don't care about the finish (or paint over them). Drill a pilot hole, and use lubrication. The wall stud is already dry, and if you overestimate the length of screw needed it can jam so hard that it breaks the bits on a power driver rather than turning any more.

Doing this correctly will prevent the door from sagging over time. Retrofitting such a long screw for one on the top hinge can improve a door that has sagged.

Answer (score -1):

It may or may not have something to do with superstition. As far as my memory of Superstition of the old goes, horse shoes and other things that had to be fixated with nails and other things were generally only fixated with 7 units.

Comment: Superstition has no place in construction when it comes to securely fastening something. Imagine your contractor saying "oh, I only used 3 screws on your 8 screw hinge because i believe in the holy trinity".

Comment: It is true but there are all sorts of people out there who do that, still I only mentioned what COULD be a reason for that.

Comment: Those missing screws, it could be aliens.

Comment: @Nzall While I definitely agree with you, OP asked as to why the screws were missing.  This is just a possible answer.  Not likely, but possible.